# Bitcoin transactions

Tags: transactions, blockchain, wallet

I recently had two transactions transferred to an address I created within my bitcoin desktop wallet to be transferred. They were transferred from a mining company, but still, are not showing up in my desktop wallet. They were transferred today, also there's something that says "reindexing blocks on disk", in my desktop wallet. The desktop wallet I am using by the way is "Bitcoin core". If anybody knows how to help me out, please I would really appreciate that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Reindexing" means that Bitcoin Core is repeating the synchronization for part of your blockchain data. Your transactions will show up once the blocks that contain them have been processed.

Comment: Ohhh ok ok I get it now. Well, I suppose that they will not show up not for now then. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you know by chance how long does this can take?

Comment: Depends on your computer, between half a day and several days. You can speed up the process by increasing the `-dbcache` if you don't mind it using more memory.

Comment: I don't mind it use it more memory. I have 16 GB of memory ram, but the problem is how do you increase the DBcache in my macbook ?

Comment: You can find instructions for that and more here: [Running Bitcoin](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin). I found those instructions as first hit when I googled "Bitcoin dbcache". :) You'll want to give 2-4 GiB if you have it.

Comment: also see: [Possible to speed up reindex?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/38422/5406)